# Laravel 5: how to find maximum used id in table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Suppose we have

- an user with `id = 1`,
- a table called `posts` with 100 entries

  - 59 of these posts belong to the user with the id 1
  - 20 of these posts belong to the user with the id 2 and the other posts to other users.

How can I count the posts for each user and show the user with the most posts like this:

```
User 1: 59 posts
User 2: 20 posts
User 3: 15 posts
...
```

Comment: Is the relationship between the user model and the posts model set? (Is there a posts model?) Using normal fluent this should be rather simple to do, but if you already have the models then it should be even simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an example may be it helps you.

```
User::join('posts', function($builder){
          $builder->on('posts.user_id', '=', 'user.id');
     })
     ->select('users.*', 'COUNT(posts.*) as total_posts')
     ->groupBy('posts.id')
     ->orderBy('total_posts', 'ASC')
     ->get();
```

you can try this example may be this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something similar to below solution:

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')
         ->select('posts.*', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
         ->groupBy('user_id')
         ->get();
```

Comment: you missed one thing in this example `sorting` by `total` posts field.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following query will work

```
Select count(id) as num_post from posts
group by (user_id)
order by (num_post) desc
```

Further you can join this with `users` table to get user data

Answer (score 0):

Using raw SQL this would be like:

```
SELECT uid, COUNT(uid) postCount
FROM posts
GROUP BY uid HAVING postCoung >= (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM posts p2 GROUP BY p2.uid);
```

If you want to convert this to Fluent:

```
DB::table(posts)
   ->SELECT("uid", DB::raw("COUNT(uid) postCount")
   ->groupBy("uid")
   ->havingRaw("postCount >= (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM posts p2 GROUP BY p2.uid)")->get();
```

In eloquent this is just a matter of using the appropriate models:

```
User::whereExists(function ($query) {
   $query->table(posts)
   ->select("uid", DB::raw("COUNT(uid) postCount")
   ->where("users.id","=","uid")
   ->groupBy("uid")
   ->havingRaw("postCount >= (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM posts p2 GROUP BY  p2.uid)")->get();
});
```